# I want to make a Kotlin to Python call using Chaquopy in Android studio

Tags: python, android, kotlin, android-studio, chaquopy

I want to be able to incorporate .py　file　using Chaquopy　in Android Studio.
But Android studio is happening the error like bellow...

Error Message①
ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64" }
↑　unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Error Message②
com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication, was not found in the project or the libraries

Supplement(version)
Android Studio Giraffe 
Chaquopy 14.0.2
Python 3.9.13

I have been following the Chaquopy's official cite and other literature and tried the hints in Android studio, but it doesn't work.

Please it would be greatly appliciated if you could explain the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for KTS build.gradle files will be added in Chaquopy 15, which should be released within the next couple of weeks. Until then, you can use a pre-release build as shown [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/934#issuecomment-1683205265):

> - At the top level of your project, edit the settings.gradle or build.gradle file to add this line to the `repositories` block within `pluginManagement` or `buildscript` (NOT within `allprojects` or `dependencyResolutionManagement`):
>
> ```
> maven { url = uri("https://chaquo.com/maven-test") }
> ```
>
> - Edit the build.gradle file to change the Chaquopy version to `15.0.0`.
> - In KTS files, you'll need to configure Chaquopy using a top-level `chaquopy` block, rather than the `python` block within `android`. For details, see the [Chaquopy 15 documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/15.0/android.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved this problem by doing Android Studio downgrade from Giraffe to Flamingo.